# How do I get the value of a soup.select?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```html
<h2 class="hello-word"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></h2>
```

How do I grab the value of the `a` tag (Google)?

```
print soup.select("h2 > a")
```

returns the entire a tag and I just want the value. Also, there could be multiple H2s on the page. How do I filter for the one with the class `hello-word`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.hello-word` on `h2` in the CSS Selector, to select only `h2` tags with class `hello-word` and then select its child `a` . Also `soup.select()` returns a list of all possible matches, so you can easily iterate over it and call each elements `.text` to get the text. Example -

```
for i in soup.select("h2.hello-word > a"):
    print(i.text)
```

---

Example/Demo (I added a few of my own elements , one with a slightly different class to show the working of the selector) -

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<h2 class="hello-word"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></h2>
... <h2 class="hello-word"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google12</a></h2>
... <h2 class="hello-word2"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google13</a></h2>"""

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')

>>> for i in soup.select("h2.hello-word > a"):
...     print(i.text)
...
Google
Google12
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

for c in soup.select("h2.hello-word > a"):
    callSign = c.get_text('href')

Why would that not work?

Comment: Because `href` is not text , its an attribute on the element `a`, use `c['href']` .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2 class="hello-word"><a     href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></h2>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.text
'Google'
```

You also can use `lxml.html` library instead

```
    >>> import lxml.html
    >>> from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
    >>> txt = '<h2 class="hello-word"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></h2>'
    >>> tree = lxml.html.fromstring(txt)
    >>> sel = CSSSelector('h2 > a')
    >>> element = sel(tree)[0]
    >>> element.text
    Google
```

Comment: This example doesn't use `soup.select`.